# Trigger.IO topbar button Border, modify

Tags: trigger.io

im triying to create  the top bar of my app but when I make a button setting the icon and tint a small border it's around the button. Is it posible to modify this propierty?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot to your question so we can see exactly what you mean?

Comment: here is the IMG (http://i.imgur.com/NrlF3k1.png) there is a small border arround the Button with black color.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not currently possible to change the appearance of the button outline. We plan to add customisations like this, and grant more complete control over the topbar appearance in general, in a future platform version.